# Spring Batch: JobExecutionDecider not working with custom ExitStatus

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-batch-tasklet

I am trying to write code that determines the step to execute based on value from the job parameter. 
In simple words here is what I need the code to do:

> intialStep to read the input filename from job parameter and determine if a particular string exists in it.
> If yes then go to the process step. 
> If no then go to the failed step

To achieve this I wrote the following code.

```
@Bean
public Step initialStep() {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("initialStep")
            .tasklet((contribution, chunkContext) -> {
                System.out.println("INTIAL STEP");
                return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
            }).listener(stepExecutionListener()).build();
}

@Bean
public StepExecutionListener stepExecutionListener() {
    return new MyStepExecutionListener();
}

static class MyStepExecutionListener implements StepExecutionListener {

    @Override
    public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        System.out.println("MyStepExecutionListener.beforeStep");
    }

    @Override
    public ExitStatus afterStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        var inputFileName = stepExecution.getJobParameters().getString("inputFileName");
        System.out.println("MyStepExecutionListener.afterStep");
        if (inputFileName != null && (inputFileName.contains("abc"))) {
            return new ExitStatus("YES", "For processing step");
        }
        return new ExitStatus("NO", "For failed step");
    }
}
```

Decider:

```
@Bean
public JobExecutionDecider decider() {
    return (jobExecution, stepExecution) -> {
        System.out.println(stepExecution.getExitStatus().getExitCode());
        if("YES".equals(stepExecution.getExitStatus().getExitCode())) {
            return new FlowExecutionStatus("YES");
        } else {
            return new FlowExecutionStatus("NO");
        }
    };
}
```

Remaining steps:

```
@Bean
public Step process() {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("process")
            .tasklet((contribution, chunkContext) -> {
                //logic to process
                return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
            }).build();
}

@Bean
public Step failedStep() {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("failedStep")
            .tasklet((contribution, chunkContext) -> {
                return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
            }).build();
}
```

Step Configuration:

```
@Bean
Job job() throws Exception {
    return jobBuilderFactory
            .get("job")
            .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
            .start(initialStep())
              .next(decider()).on("YES").to(process())
              .from(decider()).on("NO").to(failedStep()).end()
            .build();
}
```

When I run the above code the flow goes through the initial step and from their it fails. Its not going to the decider and to the further steps.

Here is the stacktrace that the application is printing on the console:

```
2023-04-03 15:41:42.865  INFO 17532 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : Job: [FlowJob: [name=job]] launched with the following parameters: [{RunDate=2023-04-03T15:41:41.080044100}]
2023-04-03 15:41:44.656  INFO 17532 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler     : Executing step: [initialStep]
MyStepExecutionListener.beforeStep
INTIAL STEP
MyStepExecutionListener.afterStep
2023-04-03 15:42:04.078  INFO 17532 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.batch.core.step.AbstractStep         : Step: [initialStep] executed in 19s422ms
2023-04-03 15:42:04.868  INFO 17532 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : Job: [FlowJob: [name=job]] completed with the following parameters: [{RunDate=2023-04-03T15:41:41.080044100}] and the following status: [FAILED] in 21s652ms
```

Any help in solving this would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Which version of Spring Batch do you use? Does it happen with v5.0.1?

Comment: I am using v4.3.5

Comment: OK thank you. I see nothing obviously wrong with what you shared. One last thing to check: can you return `null` in the listener instead of `return new ExitStatus("NO", "For failed step");`? Does the decider get invoked with that change? If not, this could be a bug in Spring Batch.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I changed No to return null. Now the code goes to the JobExecutionDecider when the fileName is not abc or when the filename is not present. But when the correct inputFileName exists the Exitstatus is `YES`, it fails going to the JobExecutionDecider and fails the application after running InitialStep.

Comment: This seems like a bug in Spring Batch. But based on how basic the requirement is, I would be surprised that you are the first user who is facing this. Please package all the code snippets in a GitHub repo or a zip file and open an issue on GitHub with all the details presented here. We will take a look deeper to validate the bug if any. Thank you upfront.